# Morrus' Unofficial Tabletop RPG News feed misbehaving in Chat

Tags: support, chat, feed

It seems that [Morrus' Unofficial Tabletop RPG News](http://www.enworld.org/forum/external.php?do=rss&type=newcontent&sectionid=1&days=120&count=10) feed has been spamming chat with lots of posts including old ones, and we're not sure what is going on.

[image]

For the time being I have removed it from the chat feed to prevent it from being a nuisance.

Anybody have any idea what is going on?

Comment: I had go google “Morrus's Unofficial Tabletop RPG News” because that link didn't work and apparently it's enworld!? What's going on with them, did they rebrand or change ownership or is this some kind of off-season prank?

Comment: @Sdjz Don't know what happened with my copypaste of that link (and thanks for pointing it out), but I think I got the right link now (had to pull it from the chat feed thread). Also thanks for the screenshot I've added it in.

Answer (score 9):

The disclaimer at the top of ENWorlds' site suggests it may be due to their upgrade.

> Welcome to this new upgrade of the site. We are now on a totally different software platform. Many things will be different, and bugs are expected. Certain areas (like downloads and reviews) will take longer to import. As always, please use the Meta Forum for site queries or bug reports. Note that we (the mods and admins) are also learning the new software.

It might be worth raising a bug on their meta as well.

Comment: Restarting RSS feeds under new software often messes up readers, since the post ID numbers change and the reader assumes everything is new. Probably they can’t easily fix it, but it’ll sort itself out here after a few days, and the feed can likely just be re-added.